# Salary is lower because I have less years of experience

Tags: salary

My salary is lower because my experience in years is less but my knowledge and work quality is higher than other employees.

What can I do? How can I deal with this kind of situation?

---

Here is a recent example with a HR team:

A few days ago I got a call from my old company.
They asked me to come back and join as a software engineer.

We had discussed about my work and salary. They really want me to come back.

I did not agree with the salary they offered, so I rejected it and continued with my current job.

A day ago I got some information from an internet source.

As per my work and knowledge they can give the salary that I was expecting but they could not offer me that much salary because if they offer the same then my salary will be higher than other employees which have more experience then I have.

Note : my field knowledge and technical knowledge is much better, that's why they want me to come back.

Comment: It's very common practise for salary to go up a: when you've worked at a company for longer (essentially a loyalty bonus) or b: when you change jobs and they one-up your current salary to tempt you away. Honestly, stick with it, do your time, and the money will likely go up. I wouldn't recommend changing to a lower-paid job unless you've got a REALLY good reason, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I suggest you sell yourself (your work) as expensive as you can. But keep in mind that employers have to keep all employees satisfied.**

In some organizations there are clear rules who gets how much depending on their education (which documents can they provide) the position and the time they are working in that organization. Everybody knows their position in that pecking order and they (have to) accept it. Such an organization is normally not attractive for better than average people.

But **even in more flexible companies the management has to make sure they keep everybody reasonably happy**. Let's say they would give you 50% more salary then others because they think you are very good. And lets say you do a very good job and they would give you even more because they know you are good.

**Consider what will happen when other people find out that you get so much more than they get.** Some will understand that you are better and you earn more. But there will be others who won't like it at all when you get more. Especially if these people think you are not so much better and if they are longer in the company then you.

What will the boss do if these people complain? Obviously he can tell them accept it and that's it. But this will be bad for their motivation. So **the boss needs to balance what he does**. If he is too good to you the others won't like it. If he is not good enough to you then you won't work there.

Maybe the boss would be willing to give you more but he can't handle problems with the others.

Maybe you can make a deal that you get a "normal" salary and a big bonus which the others don't have to know about. But depending on the company it may be difficult to hide such a deal.

**Edit:** After all the comments I like to add: **What I describe here is not the way I think things should be but the way they are.** Personally, I negotiated often enough the payment I wanted (mostly freelance work). I work mostly for small companies and I talk directly with the boss and that is confidential between him and me. But in bigger companies other people will know and sometimes this information can’t be kept secret. And then, if the lower paid people find out and get upset, this can be a huge problem for the whole company. Smart bosses avoid getting in this kind of trouble. What the lower paid people do is human nature. I cannot change it.

Comment: -1 because seriously, what other people make and how they feel is irrelevant - particularly in a time of SJW and "you hurt my feelings".

Comment: @TomTom: it might be irrelevant for you. But it is certainly not irrlevant for the management. I.e. if the management make one employee happy and at the same time ten employees unhappy then the end result is probalby not good.

Comment: It is not irrelevant for ME - it is irrelevant for the poster. Why the heck should I get less salary if the rest of the team is underperforming? The only thing from that is "go to ****" to the team while I work for someone who pays me what I am worth. Thanks for showing EXACTLY what is wrong with social whining.

Comment: Shame I can't downvote because this is so, so wrong. You shouldn't be paid based on what makes other people happy - you should be paid based on what you're worth. That's the whole point of working in a skilled trade - to be paid based on your level of skill. Positions with lower skill requirements are paid less, and people of higher skill and in-demand positions are paid more.

Comment: I think people negatively commenting on this answer are missing something.  In any negotiation, it's always important to understand the motivations of the other side.  You don't need to agree with those motivations, but understanding them helps you negotiate a better deal.  As @Edgar says that means you can do something like try and get a bonus that isn't included in salary, which helps the boss keep others happy whilst giving you what you want.

Comment: @RоryMcCune I don't have any issue with this answer it's a viewpoint and strategy worth considering, but if everyone knows everyone elses salary, that is a problem in itself, I've negotiated over 50% more than my colleagues in a place I worked at for 2 years, and none of them knew.

Comment: The comments here are misrepresenting the answer. Other people's happiness is not the _driving_ factor for market appropriate wages. However, a **manager** should strive to not upset employee morale (which includes when giving payrises to a _subset_ of employees (one person in this case)). This includes cases where morale is affected by a _perception_ that is not necessarily factually correct.

Comment: This answer has two sides to it. On the one hand, it does a fair job of explaining why an employer might not want to offer you a higher salary than the other employees; the reasons listed are valid concerns that an employer might have. On the other hand, it fails to explain why that should matter to the candidate. At the end of the day it doesn't matter at all to me *why* company A is offering me a lower salary than company B; all that matters is whether company A is willing to match B's offer, and if not, whether other factors about company A are enough to make me accept the lower pay.

Comment: @anaximander `On the other hand, it fails to explain why that should matter to the candidate.` That is wholly up to the candidate (OP) to decide. They can choose to respect the reasonable limitations of their current employer, or they can choose their employer based on the salary offered (regardless of reasonable limitations on the employer's part). We can't tell OP what he should and shouldn't think is relevant to _his_ employment. That decision should be left to the OP.

Comment: @Flater My point exactly: understanding the company's motivations is useful, but ultimately, keeping the other employees happy is not the candidate's responsibility. I'd just caution the candidate not to give too much weight to the company's reasons, because while they explain why the company would offer that salary, they have nothing to do with whethre or not the candidate should accept it. Knowing that a higher salary might displease your coworkers doesn't make it any easier to live on a lower salary than you're worth.

Comment: @Kilisi interestingly knowledge of others salaries is common in some countries, so relying on things being hidden from others isn't always an option.  also in many larger companie I've worked for bands are based on role profile and stepping out of them isn't a possibility...

Comment: @RоryMcCune I have seen it as well, just mine I don't tell... but end of the day if an employer won't give me enough, then they can either negotiate upwards or I turn them down, their problem is not mine unless I make it mine.

Comment: @Kilisi: It always helps to understand why people do something. Obviously if you are in a postition to do what you want to do then do it. I think it's important that the OP (and others) understand that sometimes the boss can't give what he thinks he should give because of other factors.

Answer (score 27):

What other people make is immaterial. What an employer is prepared to offer you is what you're worth to them.

If you feel they're not offering enough, then decline the offer or negotiate for a higher amount, but what others are getting isn't your problem, it's just a negotiating tactic.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to any question about salary negotiations. What you make is in no way dependent on what (potential) colleagues make, it's only dependent on how well you do during salary negotiations.

Comment: @Cronax: I suggest you talk with any HR expert and ask them what they think about this. I am pretty sure they won't agree with you.

Comment: And why whould anyone care what HR Experts (many of which are recruiters which seem to have a similar morale compass like what people generally asume from insurance or used car salesmen) says? Any retiremend planner will tell you to get what you are worth.

Comment: I don't know why the other answer was accepted - but this is what should be the "accepted answer". You should be paid what you're worth - not what makes everyone happy!

Comment: @Edgar Why would I be interested in making any HR experts happy. If HR says I can't get what I want because others don't get the same or more, maybe HR should give them more too. Just because others got screwed over, doesn't mean I should let myself be screwed over too. Comparing salaries is only a tool to negotiate salary. Do it when it suits you.

Comment: Other employees could only be unhappy if they knew what everyone is getting, why would they know? And why would that be the OP's problem, his/her concern is just his/her money.. If it was clear cut scaled salary, then that is different, but even then people shouldn't know the details of anyone else just the possible range.

Comment: @Horkrine Because it's (usually) not worth keeping happy one person vs whole team. If you were in a culture like e.g. asian, when seniority goes quite strictly with age, you just couldn't run a business like that. You should negotiate for yourself, HR and management for the company and overall happiness. Talk to any manager, they will tell you that you won't better money than your peers unless they (the peers) are convinced you deserve it, otherwise it's a 1st step to disrupting a team. I agree with the answer, but I find the interpretations wrong.

Comment: @Kilisi Actually, this demonstrates exactly why keeping your salary secret serves nobody but your employer. The asker has found that they can get a higher salary at Company A than people with more experience than him at Company B; in theory, if those people left and moved to Company A, they'd get paid even more. This information might be useful to those employees of Company B in negotiating for higher pay.

Comment: @anaximander I didn't join the union or vote for equality, I bought my wife a beautiful set of black pearl earrings and pendant instead all set in solid gold....edit... forgot the matching 18carat gold and pearl ring

Comment: If people find out that someone else negotiated a better salary than they did, they may be unhappy, it just means they can do better at their next salary discussion...'keeping everyone happy' really just translates to 'keeping salary costs as low as possible for the employer', which is why it's a terrible reason to get paid less.